# How is the ground state of an insulator related to a confined state and a localized state?

Tags: condensed-matter, insulators

For an insulator, the real part of the conductivity is zero, i.e., the imaginary part of the current-current correlation function is zero. How is this related to a confined state and a localized state? Is the ground state of an insulator a confined state, a localized state, or both, or neither?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confinement is usually discussed in the context of gauge theories. Here you do not have any specific information about the properties of the insulator, so it is not clear why you put "confined states" and "localized states" on the same footing.

Insulating states must have a gap for charge carriers. The gap can come in two types: 1) in a clean system, or with relatively weak disorder (I'm excluding special cases like one-dimensional metals, where an arbitrary weak disorder can cause localization), it just means there is an excitation gap for charged excitations. Ordinary band insulators, or Mott insulators belong to this category.  2) A strongly disordered system where charge carriers are localized. This is a very different situation. There may be many states below the mobility gap, but they are all exponentially localized and do not contribute to conduction.